# Two variable Floyd's Triangle Pattern

Tags: java, c++

How to create Floyd's triangle using only 2 variables?

I am using this logic but it is using 3 variables but I only want to create it with 2.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   {
     cout<<k;
     k++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLOYD's Triangle pattern

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(){
  int i=1,j=1,n;
  cout<<"input the value \"n\" upto which FLOYD's triangle needed to print \n"
  cin>>n;
  while(i<=n){ //here we use only two variable that is "i" and "j";
    cout<<    i   <<" ";//if you are confused with pattern then comment these statement and use below statement. 
    //cout<<"* ";
    if(i>=j*(j+1)/2){
      cout<<"\n";
      j++;
    }
    i++;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if i want to do it with the help of number of rows and columns.